# Can an inner class retrieve the instance of the top class?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes, instance-variables

The program I am working on uses nested classes. The top class is named `Brain` which has two inner classes, `Neuron` and `Axon`. The inner classes need to be able to modify the instance variables of the top class.

`Brain` keeps track of how many neurons and axons have been instantiated. `Neuron` holds information regarding its action potential and its outputs. `Axon` determines how to traverse the energy from one neuron to another. This way whenever I instantiate a neuron, it is saved within the instance of the brain. The same goes for the axon.

---

This is my code so far:

```
class Brain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.neurons = []
        self.axons = []

    class Neuron(object):
        def __init__(self, pos, AP_Energy, AP_threshold):
            # General attributes
            self.outputs = {}
            self.Energy = 0
            self.x, self.y = pos[0], pos[1]

            # Action Potential attributes
            self.AP_Energy = AP_Energy
            self.AP_threshold = AP_threshold

            """Append self to instance
               of Brain in neurons"""

        def add(self, value): self.Energy += value
        def link(self, neuron, weight): self.outputs[neuron] = weight

        def act(self):
            for neuron in self.outputs.keys():
                """Append Axon(self, neuron) to
                   instance of Brain in axons"""

    class Axon(object):
        def __init__(self, n1, n2):
            # Neurons
            self.n1, self.n2 = n1, n2

            # Action Potential attributes
            self.wavelength = sqrt((5*n1.AP_Energy)/3)
            self.distance = sqrt((n2.x-n1.x)**2+(n2.y-n1.y)**2)

        def action_potential(self): # Bunch of math stuff
```

---

The idea is that you can create neurons without having to include the instance of the brain as one of its arguments. Therefore, if I want to create an instance of `Brain` with two neurons, it should appear as so:

```
EntityA = Brain()
EntityA.Neuron((0, 1), 15, 24)
EntityA.Neuron((4, 2), 30, 41)
```

And if I need to call `add()` from the first neuron in `EntityA`, I should be able to refer to it as `EntityA.neurons[0].add(value)` since as I create the neurons it should automatically append itself to the list.

How would I go about doing this, and if it's not possible what can be done to give a similar result?

---

**Edit**: Using a function to both instantiate the class `Neuron` and saving it into a list within an instance of `Brain` seems the obvious answer. The *problem* occurs in the function `Neuron.act()` which instantiates the class `Axon` and must save it into a list that is in the *same* instance of `Brain` as used for the neuron. The previous constraints still apply.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use nested classes? Any advantage?

Comment: Well I need that as I create instances of the Neuron class it is saved into an instance of the Brain class. However I don't know how to go about doing this without including the Brain instance as one of its argument. The nested class idea was the only one I thought could produce what I want but then I got stuck as I began coding it.

Comment: Nested classes are almost never necessary, and rarely useful in Python (although, *sometimes* they are legitimate). It seems better to simply have three seperate classes, not nested, and have a method on brain that creates and adds a neuron to some internal list.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Something like `EntityA.Neuron((0, 1), 15, 24)` except it automatically adds a neuron to `EntityA`? Again, sure, just simply make `Neuron` a method on `Entitiy` that creates and adds a `Nueron` to some internal list. Using nested classes, probably no clean way, although, there is a lot of meta-class magic you can do that might get you seomthing like what you want, but it woudl probably be pretty over-engineered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Brain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.neurons = []
        self.axons = []

    class Neuron(object):
        ...

    class Axon(object):
        ...

    def add_neuron(self, pos, AP_Energy, AP_threshold):
        self.neurons.append(Brain.Neuron(pos, AP_Energy, AP_threshold))


EntityA = Brain()
EntityA.add_neuron((0, 10), 15, 24)
```